# ¿Esta bien instanciar desde "class" directamente?

Tags: javascript

[image: Javascript class]

Tengo entendido que en javascript todo es un objeto. 
Al realizar estos ejemplos me di cuenta de que las dos formas de declarar 
el objeto que necesito retorna lo mismo, ¿esta correcto hacer esto?

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Te lo explico bajo 2 ejemplos los 2 escenarios que tienes; pues en uno
>   la clase tiene un nombre que la identifica y en otro es una clase
>   anónima que esta siendo asignada como valor de una constante/variable

**clase anónima**

> Cuando declaras una clase anónima, como en tu primer escenario; por
>   ejemplo no vas a poder llevar a cabo el proceso de herencia, dado lo
>   cual una clase anónima esta limitada por ese aspecto; segundo punto en
>   una clase anónima como ya pudiste notar no requieres instanciar un
>   objeto para acceder a sus métodos, basta con que lleves a cabo la sintáxis de `variable.método`

```js
const datos = new class{
  hello(){
    return 'Hello Worl';
  }
}

let obj = datos.hello()
console.log(obj)
```

**clase nombrada**

> Para tu segundo caso la clase si posee un nombre, por lo cual puede
>   heredar sus propiedades y métodos a una clase hija, además de eso
>   cuando necesitas acceder a sus propieades y atributos deberás llevar a
>   cabo el proceso de instanciación, como en este ejemplo

```js
class Mundo 
{
  bye(){
    return 'Adios mundo';
  }
}

let dato = new Mundo
console.log(dato.bye())
```

Comment: OK, entendí perfectamente. No conocía el concepto de clase anónima, me pareció natural hacerlo de la primera manera si es que no necesitaba la herencia, gracias.

Comment: Creo que hay un error en tu explicación para *clase anónima*: `no requieres instanciar un objeto para acceder a sus métodos`. ¿ Seguro que querías decir eso ? Porqué si haces `new`, estás instanciando algo ¿ no ?

Comment: @Trauma la instanciación si la hice pero en la clase que tiene nombre, en la clase que es anónima no esta instanciada